# Whats the number of data in each K-Means Cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have wrote a code that will give me the best number of clusters based on max value of `silhouette_score`. Now I want to find out how many values each cluster have. For example,  my result is that the optimal number of clusters is 3, I want to find out how many values each cluster have, for example first cluster has 1241 values second 3134 values and third 351 values.
Is it possible to do something like that?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re 
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, MiniBatchKMeans, AffinityPropagation

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score
from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_mutual_info_score

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df = pd.read_csv('CNN Comments.csv')
df = df.head(8000)
#print(df)
x = df['Text Data']

cv = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'word',max_features = 10000, preprocessor=None, lowercase=True, tokenizer=None, stop_words = 'english')
#cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', max_features = 8000, preprocessor=None, lowercase=True, tokenizer=None, stop_words = 'english')  

x = cv.fit_transform(x)

my_list = []
list_of_clusters = []
for i in range(2,5):

    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42)
    kmeans.fit(x)
    my_list.append(kmeans.inertia_)

    cluster_labels = kmeans.fit_predict(x)

    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(x, cluster_labels) * 100
    print(round(silhouette_avg,2))
    list_of_clusters.append(round(silhouette_avg, 1))


plt.plot(range(2,5),my_list)
plt.show()


number_of_clusters = max(list_of_clusters)
number_of_clusters = list_of_clusters.index(number_of_clusters)+2

print('Number of clusters: ', number_of_clusters)
```

Comment: A whole bunch of code, including stuff completely irrelevant to the question (PCA, TF-IDF, plots, prints, scores etc) is arguably not a good practice; you could very easily make a [MCVE] with the toy data available in the [KMeans documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) example (I kindly suggest you keep it in mind for the future)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the array assigned to `cluster_labels` to get the distribution of cluster assignments.  I would recommend using `Counter` from the collections module.

```py
from collections import Counter

...

cluster_labels = kmeans.fit_predict(x)
cluster_counts = Counter(cluster_labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternativ with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
...
unique, counts = np.unique(kmeans.fit_predict(x), return_counts=True)
print(dict(zip(unique, counts)))
```